# How to include font awesome and other customizations in django forms for Sign up using allauth

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using django-allauth in my project and want to customize the signup form. I know that we can create forms in app/forms.py and assign classes to element there. But i also want to add font awsome icons and other customizations. 
Sample fields in form:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Full Name</label>
            <div class="input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" id="signup-full-name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullname" />
            </div>
            <p class="login-error" id="invalid-full-name">This field is required</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Email</label>
            <div class="input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" id="signup-email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
            </div>
            <p class="login-error" id="invalid-email">This field is required</p>
        </div>
```

How can i do this in django. I went through many similar questions on this portal, but none of then discuss customizations upto this level

Comment: Write forms manually in HTML if icons are so important.

Comment: @xyres then will i be able to use SignupView in allauth? Because it uses ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS field in settings to save the signup form

Comment: Yes, why not. Every form gets rendered to HTML after all. When writing forms manually , you just need to set the correct `name` on input fields and the correct form `action`.